# QGIS: Only view raster data within polygon

Tags: qgis, raster

So i have this raster dataset in .ASC-format. I defined a bounding box polygon of my study area:

[image]

Now i want QGIS to only show the raster data within this boundary box without changing/adapting the data or making new files. Is this possible?

Comment: Can you make a polygon bounding box of the raster layer, and then clip out the smaller bounding box? Then you could use that as a visual mask without adapting the raster layer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution, *only for display purpose*: change the the style of your boundary box to "Inverted polygons" (top left box in `Properties > Style`), then change the color of the box to white or whatever, without transparency.

Note that it won't make QGIS display your area faster, since all of your raster will still be rendered "behind" the bounding box.